# How do I open ports in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, port

I have connected my mobile to my PC which runs Windows 7. I can't open ports in Windows 7.

I know in Windows Vista there's supposed to be an Add Ports button in `Control Panel/All Control Panel Items/Windows Firewall/Allowed Programs`, but in Windows 7, there is no button for this. All you can do is add programs; you can't open specific ports.

How do I open ports in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the advanced firewall settings.

You can find this by pressing `WIN+R` and entering `wf.msc`. You can also find the advanced settings in `Control Panel/System and security/Windows Firewall/Advanced settings`. Here, you can add new policies to your inbound and outbound rules for both programs and ports.

Per example, here is how you open up port 80 for inbound traffic:

1. Go to "Inbound Rules"
2. Click on "New Rule..." in the actions list
3. Select "Port"
4. Choose whether you want to apply your rule to TCP or UDP traffic
5. Enter 80 in the textbox
6. Choose "Allow the connection"
7. Check where the rule should apply
8. Give it a nice name.

Make sure to pay attention to what you do however as it is very possible to introduce security risks here.